# Rank of the product of two full rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, rank

I have searched for the above topic and found some results, but the answer i am looking for is not found anywhere. Here is my question:

`Given A(m×n) matrix with rank n, and B(n×p) matrix with rank p,` i know that

`rank(AB) ≤ min(rank(A),rank(B))`.

What i want to know is if this expression holds for equality. i.e is this expression

`rank(AB) = min(rank(A),rank(B))` correct?

If yes, how can it be proved?

Please your help on this is highly welcomed.

Comment: Hello and welcome on stackoverflow. We talk here about programming tools, techniques, languages, etc. This looks like a maths question, which would belong there I believe: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Rank(AB) can be zero while neither rank(A) nor rank(B) are zero. For example

```
A = ( 1 0 ) and B ( 0 ) both have rank 1, but their product, 0, has rank 0
                  ( 1 )
```

Comment: So equality does not hold?